# In a PID, every principal ideal is free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $R$ is a PID and let $a \in R$ be non-zero.
I want to prove that $aR$ is free as an $R$-module.

 If I consider the map $\phi:R \rightarrow aR$, given by $\phi(r)=ar$, then this is an isomorphism of $R$-modules. Does this mean that $aR$ is free?

Comment: I would read the definition of "free", prove that $R$ itself is free, then see if that can't be leveraged together with $\phi$ to show that $aR$ is free.

Comment: Yes, and $\{a\}$ is a basis. More generally, for any ring, an $R$-module is free if it is isomorphic to some $R^{(X)}$, where $X$ is any set.

Answer (score 1):

For this result to hold, would it not be sufficient for $R$ to be an integral domain? You're not really using the PID condition here.

Comment: +1 I half suspect the original question said: "In a PID, every ideal is free."

Comment: yeah was my first thought as well.